# Crystal Report Viewer (web viewer) doesn't display drill down in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, crystal-reports

I have an application with crystal reports which I've just noticed has a fairly large issue.  The treeview/drill-down menu on the left will not display in Internet Explorer, however it does work with other browsers (chrome/firefox/etc.).  I've never used CR before (these are actually inherited, I haven't touched them), but I'm guessing it's an IE option that's not set some where.  Any idea how to fix this?

[image: Internet Explorer missing the left panel]

[image: Chrome with the left panel]

**EDIT:**

Per the question about browser version, I am working with IE8.  I did notice that when compatibility mode was turned off, it displays as I would expect.  However, the app is supposed to handle IE7 (which I do not have access to) as well.

Comment: What version of IE are you using?